# Unable to push code to gitLab it was workig an hour before

Tags: git, push, gitlab

when i run `git push origin master` it returned.

> ssh: connect to host gitlab.camper-spot.com port 22: Connection timed
>   out fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

my global configurations are correct

```
git config --global -l
```

user.email=usman.sharif525@gmail.com

user.name=MANA

Comment: Is there any chance that your user was altered on the remote server?  Does anyone else in your team have this problem?

Comment: this is something problem with your net connection. Its time out. Are you able to pull it from master?